# Show active state after CSS transition is done without javascript

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a link with CSS transitions:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="spin circle" id="link">Hover</a>
```

CSS

```
.circle::before, .circle::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.spin:hover {
  color: #0eb7da;
}
.spin::before, .spin::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.spin::before {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.spin:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #0eb7da;
  border-right-color: #0eb7da;
  border-bottom-color: #0eb7da;
  -webkit-transition: border-top-color 0.15s linear, border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.1s, border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.2s;
  transition: border-top-color 0.15s linear, border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.1s, border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.2s;
}
.spin::after {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}
.spin:hover::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #0eb7da;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.4s linear 0s;
  transition: border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.4s linear 0s;
  transition: transform 0.4s linear 0s, border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.4s linear 0s, border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.4s linear 0s;
}
```

On hover, I animate/draw a border around my link. It works as expected. After the hover animation is done, I want my link to retain the border.

So the experience is like this -> I hover around different links. It animates and shows the active state (with the border around it).

I believe this can only be done if I have a class (e.g. .active). I tried adding the border(final) with a delay (after the initial animation is done) with no luck.

**Is it possible to do this without delaying the adding of class via javascript?**

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybrEjM

Comment: yeah sound like you want to use the `transitionend` event. do you ever want the circle to go away after it's been hovered and `.active` has been applied?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I want it to go away if i hover on different link.

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/eWoLdq

Comment: @MichaelCoker Awesome.Thank you.